# StrongSwan build and run at startup

Tags: strongswan

I've been asked to deploy an IPSEC server for a project and after doing some research, StrongSwan looks like a good candidate. Since this project requires top security, I decided to install the latest version of StrongSwan (5.6.2) as it seems to fix a few security issues and what-not.

So I've spent the past few days working out how to configure it, which I have been able to do using `/etc/ipsec.conf`, however, on reading StrongSwan's website, is now a legacy way of setting it up.

> The recommended way of configuring strongSwan is via the powerful vici
>   interface and the swanctl command line tool. The swanctl.conf
>   configuration file used by swanctl is stored together with
>   certificates and corresponding private keys in the swanctl directory.
>   Global strongSwan settings as well as plugin-specific configurations
>   are defined in strongswan.conf.
>
> Alternatively the legacy ipsec stroke interface and its ipsec.conf and
>   ipsec.secrets configuration files may be used.

So now I am in the process of trying to change the configuration to use a file stored in `/etc/swanctl/conf.d` instead...

**So my question is this:**

Does anyone know how to build StrongSwan from source and have it start with the Server (Ubuntu 16.04) and use the new configuration method?

My configure line looks like this

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc \
  --enable-systemd --enable-swanctl \
  --disable-charon --disable-stroke --disable-scepclient \
  --enable-gcm --enable-eap-tls
```

but this still doesnt start with the Server, nor can I find any `strongswan` or `strongswan-swanctl` for startup.

My current `ipsec.conf` looks like this

```
conn %default
 auto=add
 forceencaps=yes
 keyexchange=ikev2
 keyingtries=1
 ike=aes256-sha256-modp2048!
 esp=aes256-sha256,aes128-sha256!
 dpdaction=clear
 inactivity=120s
 leftsendcert=always
 leftcert=vpn-server-cert.pem
 leftsubnet=10.0.0.0/20
 leftid=@vpnserver
 rightsourceip=172.16.0.0/12
 eap_identity=%identity

conn ikev2-cert
 rightauth=eap-tls
```

which 'I think' translates to this

```
connections {
   rw {
      version = 2
      send_certreq = yes
      proposals = aes256-sha256-modp2048!
      encap = yes
      dpd_delay = 30s
      local {
         auth = eap-tls 
         certs = vpn-server-cert.pem
         id = vpnserver
      }
      remote {
         auth = eap-tls 
      }
      children {
         net {
            local_ts  = 172.16.0.0/12 
            esp_proposals = aes256-sha256,aes128-sha256!
            inactivity = 120s
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you configure with `--enable-systemd` the `charon-systemd` daemon will be built and a systemd service unit named `strongswan` will be installed. You can manage that (like any other systemd unit) with `systemctl`.  So to start it at system boot enable the unit with:

```
sudo systemctl enable strongswan.service
```

(**Note:** The systemd service unit was called `strongswan-swanctl` before [5.8.0](https://wiki.strongswan.org/versions/73).)

Also, a more accurate translation of the config is the following:

```
connections {
   rw {
      version = 2
      send_cert = always
      proposals = aes256-sha256-modp2048
      encap = yes
      pools = rw
      # dpd_delay = 30s you didn't specify this in your ipsec.conf and it seems rather short for roadwarriors
      local {
         certs = vpn-server-cert.pem
         id = vpnserver
      }
      remote {
         auth = eap-tls 
         eap_id = %any
      }
      children {
         net {
            local_ts  = 10.0.0.0/20
            esp_proposals = aes256-sha256,aes128-sha256
            inactivity = 120s
         }
      }
   }
}

pools {
   rw {
     addrs = 172.16.0.0/12 
   }
}
```

Comment: I have included `--enable-eap-identity` to be used with `eap_id = %any`

Comment: I should add that I have also moved the certs from `/etc/ipsec.d/[private|certs|cacerts]` to `/etc/swanctl/[private|x509|x509ca]`

Comment: Got it!  Thanks for your help.  Weirdly I had to recreate the certificates.

Comment: Why did you have to recreate the certificates?

Comment: When connecting, I was getting the error `ikev2_crypto_remote_cert_and_s:3166 Certificate is not trusted` but I hadn't changed anything on the client (OSX Sierra)

Comment: And just recreating the certificates fixed this?

Comment: yep............

Comment: I can't connect to the VPN from Windows10 (first time trying though).  Any help?  I notice in Windows VPN settings, you cant set the `Local ID`

Comment: Could be a lot of things. Logs would help. Try to start [here](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/HelpRequests).

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/906205/strongswan-connecting-from-windows-10

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to add something on top of what "ecdsa" anwser above.

For the people that have just installed strongswan using the ubuntu packages and not with ./configure ... build.

If you can't find the service "strongswan-swanctl" or you can't install it, the package name in ubuntu is "charon-systemd".

So to install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install charon-systemd
```

And to enable the service:

```
systemctl enable strongswan-swanctl
```